# Convergence of a sequence $a_{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, formal-proofs

Suppose that $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence such that $ a_{2n-1}\leq a_{2n+1} \leq a_{2n+2} \leq a_{2n+4}$. Prove that if $(a_{n})$ converges, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a_{n}-a_{n+1}) = 0$.

Edit: so my basic idea of a solution involves taking the subsequence of even-indexed terms, which can be shown to be monotonously increasing and the subsequence of odd-indexed terms and saying that if the limit converges to a limit $L$.

Comment: This is not true take $a_n=\sqrt n$

Comment: Sorry about that! I made a typo.

Comment: If $a_n$ converges than simply $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}-a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}-\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. We only used that $a_n$ converges, are you sure this version is okay?

Comment: It's definitely not supposed to be that simple! And idk, but maybe there's a condition that's missing. The work you've done is too simple for this question. It can't possibly be right!

Comment: Unless you have that condition we really can't help you. As it's written the answer is indeed simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(a_n)$ converge. Then:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}|(a_{n+1}-a_n)|\leq \lim_{n \to \infty}  |a_n-a|+\lim_{n \to \infty}  |a_{n+1}-a|=0
$$
This is true since $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ converge to the same limit. 
If you assume convergence of $a_n$, you dont need to "monoticity requirement" at all.
Additional note: 
$$
|a_{n+1}-a_n|\leq |a_{n+1}-a|+|a-a_n|
$$
by the triangle inequality.

Comment: That's wayyyy too simpleeee!!! And I know that basic stuff already! Just use $\epsilon/2$ to show that $a_{n+1}-a_{n} < \epsilon \forall \epsilon$. That's not helpful!!! The problem IS NOT SUPPOSED to be THAT EASY!

Comment: It is the answer to your question! You said "If $(a_n)$ converges", then it is indeed simple to show that $a_{n+1}-a_n \to 0$. So I can already assume the convergence of $a_n$. 
If you want help regarding the convergence of $(a_n)$, you have to re-write your question.